# PHP double and single quotes causing trouble

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, quotes

I have a jQuery script:
`$('[id="a"][f-id="0"]').val(<?php  echo $a; ?>)`
Now i want to put this script inside a PHP variable `$output` and return it via the PHP function.
But those quotes in script are causing lots of syntax errors.
Can anyone make this running?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the characters using backslash?

Comment: What syntax errors? Javascript or php ones? Also looks like you need to change that to this: `.val('<?php  echo $a; ?>')`. or use json_encode: `.val(<?php  echo json_encode($a); ?>)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to put the Javascript string in your question into a PHP variable. This would look like this:

```
$myVar = "$('[id=\"a\"][f-id=\"0\"]').val($a)";
```

The backslashes () before the double quotes are escape characters that let PHP know that you want the actual character " to be in the string, otherwise PHP thinks you want to end the string.

Note that the $a doesn't need to be echoed in this context, because you're not outputting $a, but rather including it in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to put a backslash before the quotes (\). This will tell the PHP compiler that the next sign (the " or ') has to be literal and not the end of the string.

If you wnt to put a backslash, you need "\".